# Replace last occurrence to end of string using Twig preg_replace

Tags: php, string, symfony, twig, preg-replace

I am using Twig templating for PHP with plugin (https://github.com/jasny/twig-extensions) that includes functions like preg_replace.

I have the follow strings:

```
Coverking_CSC_Neosupreme_1Row-F-150_Series-01-MASS 
Coverking_CSC_Neosupreme_1Row-F-150_Series-01-ANYTHING
Coverking_CSC_Neosupreme_1Row-F-150_Series-01
```

I want to replace the last occurrence of -XX or -XXANYTHING with empty string.

So the results of replacements for all strings above should be

```
Coverking_CSC_Neosupreme_1Row-F-150_Series
```

I managed to look online and found the following regular expression to remove the last occurrence of -XX

```
str|preg_replace("/\-[0-9]{2}(?!.*\-[0-9]{2})/","")
```

How can I modify the above regex to give me the desired results?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
preg_replace("/-\d\d(-.*|)$/","","Coverking_CSC_Neosupreme_1Row-F-150_Series-01-MASS");
```

Comment: Thank you @l-vadim. I should have added an additional scenario. The string may not end in "-MASS". It may just simply end with "-XX" or "-XX-ANYTHING".

Comment: I updated, now it working with all scenarios, including  Coverking_CSC_Neosupreme_1Row-F-150_Series-01

Comment: Yes, that works. You were just missing $ at end of the regex. So it should "/-\d\d(-.*|)$/"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip anything from the `-XX-` up until the end, use the `$` anchor character to define you want to match up until the last character of the string.

You can do something like this:

`{{ str|preg_replace("/\-[0-9]{2}(\-[\w\-]+)?$/", "") }}`

The \w matches 0-9 A-Z and a-z.

See regex in action:

https://regex101.com/r/aiKMDn/2

edit:

Updated regex to have anything after `-XX` as optional match up until the end of the string.